# Amazon Listing Data Import

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to import the product titles and review ratings from a listing to a Google Spreadsheet. I have tried the ImportXML fuction using Xpath query but that does not work. So, I tried a code as mentioned below and it worked. I have been able to get the listing data but sometimes it gives me an error instead of displaying the data.

**Error:**

> Request failed for https://www.amazon.co.uk returned code 503. Truncated server response:  For information about migrating to ... (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response). (line 2).

When I refresh the code or when I add/remove https:// from the url, it works again but when I refresh the sheet, it goes off sometime and displays the error.

**Question:**

1. Is there any way to get rid of the error?
2. While trying to get the Star Rating displayed on the sheet, it uses a Span Data-hook class where the data is stored and I am unable to retrieve it. Is there any way to retrieve the star rating as well?

This is the function that I have created to get the product title and other data:

```
    function productTitle(url) {   
      var content = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
      var match = content.match(/<span id="productTitle".*>([^<]*)<\/span>/);
      return match && match [1] ? match[1] : 'Title not found';
    }
```

Comment: Could you please provide the full error message and share a sanitized version of your sheets so we can properly troubleshoot this?

Comment: Hi Zektor,

Thank you for your help. This is the link to access my sheet.

[https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SNFmIFmrgyAobNp_AZkm4ODJEZoIbrsHsFT4KXtfWZM/edit?usp=sharing]

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving [HTTP Status codes of 503](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/503), that means the service you are trying to reach is either under maintenance or overloaded.

This is on Amazon's side. You should use the Amazon API instead of the public endpoints for processing this data.

Comment: I've found a fix to this. Upon further research, I found that while trying to get the data, my code was not able to bypass the captcha that Amazon had due to which I was receiving the error. So, I changed the URL to a different one and it is working for me at the moment.

Now I'm stuck at a different place, I am looking to get the Star Rating (For ex: 4 out of 5, 5 out of 5, 3.5 out of 5) of a product. While trying to pull the data by inspecting the element, it is returning me the same result as of review count.

I'll make changes to my sheet so that you can look at it.

Comment: Please, to keep Stack Overflow relevant, post a new question instead of editing your question for each new issue you face while developing. Also, remember to assign correct tags and provide samples. Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as well.